# Is it possible to use \code in doxygen 1.8.14 in VHDL descriptions?

Tags: vhdl, doxygen

For C++ code, doxygen has no insurmountable problem with `\code{.markdown}`. 
For example

```
//===========================================================================
//! \defgroup markdown_cpp C++ markdown test
//! \brief         test cpp markdown
//! \date          2018 March
//!
//! \code{.markdown}
//!         ______ 
//!        |      |
//!   x ->-|      |->- y
//!        |______|
//! \endcode
//===========================================================================
int test(void)
  {
  const unsigned x=3;
  return x*2;
  }
```

and it produces in a `.tex` file

```
\begin{DoxyCode}
      \_\_\_\_\_\_ 
     |      |
x ->-|      |->- y
     |\_\_\_\_\_\_|
\end{DoxyCode}
```

However, in VHDL code, doxygen crashes on Windows 10 ("doxygen.exe has stopped working")
when I attempt this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--! \defgroup markdown_vhd VHDL markdown test
--! \ingroup  markdown_vhd
--!
--! \code{.markdown}
--!            ______ 
--!           |      |
--!     x1 ->-|      |
--!           |      |->- y
--!     x2 ->-|      |
--!           |______|
--! \endcode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity test is
  port (--inpts
         x1 : in  std_logic;
         x2 : in  std_logic;
        --outputs
          y : out std_logic;
        );
end entity test;

architecture test_arch of test is
begin
  y <= x1 xor x2;
end architecture test_arch;
```

Comment: Probably a bug? The correct place for this post would be the Doxygen mailing list, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When it is a bug the right place is not the a mailing list but in bugzilla (see http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/trouble.html#bug_reports)

Comment: @albert: If/when it is determined to be a bug, yes.

Comment: Well in my opinion a crash is always a bug even when it is a result of usage. I checked and the problem looks like to come from the \code (also an empty \code crashes). Please submit a bug report to bugzilla.

Comment: Thank you both for both the mailing list and bugzilla suggestions. I will submit the issue to one or both of these.

Comment: I did file a bug report with time stamp 2018-03-21 15:31 UTC here:
  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794567
In the meantime, might anyone know of any personally proven way (not just something read in a manual) of including Doxygen extractable markdown in VHDL code with 
    OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = YES
in the Doxyfile?

Comment: As far as I can see the given example contains a small violation against the VHDL standard, paragraph 6.5.6 Interface lists (This is not the reason for the doxygen crash). The line ```y : out std_logic;``` should read ```y : out std_logic```, so with the ```;```. The last ```interface_element``` in an ```interface_list``` should have no ```;```.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for your doxygen comment in your example is correct. This is resulting in a crash which is a bug (tested in doxygen 1.8.11 in windows).

All commands in the documentation start with a backslash (\) or an at-sign (@), see [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html). 
To achieve the exact same (intended) result, use the following:

```
--! @code{.markdown}
--!            ______ 
--!           |      |
--!     x1 ->-|      |
--!           |      |->- y
--!     x2 ->-|      |
--!           |______|
--! @endcode
```

It will not crash in doxygen (tested in 1.8.11 on windows).

**produced html result for code:**
[image: produced html result for code]

You may also be interested in the following variant:

```
--! \verbatim
--!            ______ 
--!           |      |
--!     x1 ->-|      |
--!           |      |->- y
--!     x2 ->-|      |
--!           |______|
--! \endverbatim
```

The outcome is different:

**produced html result for verbatim:**
[image: produced html result for verbatim]

Note 1: I do not have the latest version installed on my machine which is why I used an slightly older version. It will hopefully not affect the provided solution.

Note 2: Workaround had been successfully tested for 1.8.14 by OP.

Comment: Interesting observation (the difference between ```@``` and ```\```)!

Comment: In version 1.8.14 the line numbers are gone in the ```@code``` part.

Comment: Please add the images inline as at that moment people can directly see the result (and the links might not be persistent).

Comment: you can add the images now. Regarding the manual reference, indeed the ```\``` and ```@``` versions should give the same results.

Comment: Many thanks M24 for your working solutions, and many thanks to @albert for pointing out my VHDL error.
I tried both of M24 's  @code...@endcode and \verbatim...\endverbatim with Doxygen 1.8.14 on Windows 10 with LaTeX pdf output. I did try to include more information here, but it seems the length the post is limited by the system.

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 684, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/684).

Comment: In the mean time the patch has been integrated in master on github.

Answer (score 0):

All of the following work for Doxygen 1.8.14 on Windows 10:

```
--!
--! @code{.markdown}
--!            ______ 
--!           |      |
--!     x1 ->-|      |
--!           |      |->- y
--!     x2 ->-|      |
--!           |______|
--! @endcode
--!
--! \verbatim
--!            ______ 
--!           |      |
--!     x1 ->-|      |
--!           |      |->- y
--!     x2 ->-|      |
--!           |______|
--! \endverbatim
--!
--! @verbatim
--!            ______ 
--!           |      |
--!     x1 ->-|      |
--!           |      |->- y
--!     x2 ->-|      |
--!           |______|
--! @endverbatim
```

These produce the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{DoxyCode}
       \_\_\_\_\_\_ 
      |      |
x1 ->-|      |
      |      |->- y
x2 ->-|      |
      |\_\_\_\_\_\_|
\end{DoxyCode}


\begin{DoxyVerb}            ______ 
           |      |
     x1 ->-|      |
           |      |->- y
     x2 ->-|      |
           |______|\end{DoxyVerb}


\begin{DoxyVerb}            ______ 
           |      |
     x1 ->-|      |
           |      |->- y
     x2 ->-|      |
           |______|\end{DoxyVerb}
```

The --! leads are completely stripped out with @code, replaced with spaces (plus an additional space) with the \verbatim and @verbatim. The DoxyCode environment is defined as

```
\newenvironment{DoxyCode}{%
  \par%
  \scriptsize%
  \begin{alltt}%
}{%
  \end{alltt}%
  \normalsize%
}
```

where alltt is defined in the alltt package: https://ctan.org/pkg/alltt
and the DoxyVerb is defined as

```
\newenvironment{DoxyVerb}{%
  \footnotesize%
  \verbatim%
}{%
  \endverbatim%
  \normalsize%
}
```

Note that the verbatim methods typeset larger ("\footnotesize") than the @code ("\scriptsize").

Many many thanks to @M24 for very helpful help.

Comment: I posted the above in response to the above, "does this mean you confirm operation for v. 1.8.14?" But I don't seem to see the user name "M24". Many apologies if I didn't give proper credit. I should have credited "TheUltimateSource"?